# ERROR in node_modules/@clr/angular/popover/common/popover-host-anchor.token.d.ts(2,58): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using clarity-ui for building my application.
I just did npm update and rebuil my application and it has stoppoed working
Getting below error

```
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your 
browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2018-06-18T08:38:02.478Z                                                       
Hash: 938331c2d2650db9b80f
Time: 5293ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 2.91 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 577 bytes [initial]     [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 1.23 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 852 kB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in node_modules/@clr/angular/popover/common/popover-host-    anchor.token.d.ts(2,58): error TS2315: Type 'ElementRef' is not generic.




npm --version 
6.1.0

node --version 
v6.14.3
```

Comment: are you using ng-bootstrap or material?

Comment: If you are using Material 6 you need to make sure that your angular core is also updated to >6. Otherwise you need to downgrade to material 5.

Comment: NO i am not using Material 6

Comment: What version of Angular and Clarity do you have?

Comment: "@clr/ui": "^0.12.0"
@angular/core": "^5.2.0",